# Stop CKEditor removing divs

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

I've installed CKEditor in the backend of my website.
I've got the following problem when switching from code view to wysiwyg view.
The code I'm inserting is like:

```
<div class="span4">
    <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

When I switch back to view mode CKEditor automatically removes the div surrounding the paragraph.

Can anyone please help me to remove this problem? I don't mind staying in code view but I do like working in the view mode for writing longer text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding this in ckeditor config file `config.protectedSource.push( %\<.*\>.*\</.*\>%i );`

Comment: Are you using CKEditor 4.1? That version includes a new "ACF" that removes anything that isn't allowed by it's toolbar buttons.

Comment: Yes, I'm using v4.1.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of disabling the ACF feature, use [config.extraAllowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent):

```
editor.config.extraAllowedContent = 'div(span4)';
```

or

```
editor.config.extraAllowedContent = 'div(*)';
```

Answer (score 11):

Like AlfonsoMl said, this has something to do with the Advanced Content Filter

For all support about this look here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter

or put the following line in your config to disable the content filter. (It's better to configure it)

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

Comment: You don't have to disable the entire feature because of a single tag.

Comment: You didn't read my post. See the part that says: "It's better to configure it" .... The fact that i know little about the ACF is the exact reason that i posted the url to the explanations.

Answer (score 2):

```
var editor1=CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
editor1.config.allowedContent = true;
```