# CKeditor setData() method is omitting images

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

when setting data in CKEditor images disappear in the editor area. Links and other format is ok, so doesn't look like a double quote thing. Also, I tryed with absolute positioned and also external images, so it's not an *image not found* problem.

This is my code:

```
function getContent(id)
{
    console.log($('#content-article-' + id).html());

    return $('#content-article-' + id).html();
}
function enableEdition()
{
    if (current_conclusion != 'NEW')
    {
        $('#titular-edit').val(getTitle(current_article));

        //This setData() sets everthing but images
        CKEDITOR.instances.editor.setData(getContent(current_article));
    }
}
```

The image tag is substituted by a `<br>` tag inside the editor iframe

Comment: Which version of ckeditor are you using?

Comment: Last one, Version 4.1.2 • 23 Apr 2013 standard package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CKEditor 4.1 comes with [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) which is the root of your problem. Most likely you don't use the image plugin that adds `<img>` to `allowedContent` rules (don't you?). This is why editor discards those tags from your content and this is why you have to configure it manually.

See related answers: [Stop CKEditor removing divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799778/stop-ckeditor-removing-divs/16808074#16808074), [CKEditor strips inline attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753956/ckeditor-strips-inline-attributes/15758342#15758342)

Comment: I went for the easy config as I didn't find specific examples for my image plugin (doksoft): `config.allowedContent = true;` in ckeditor *config.js*.

Comment: @K.Weber This would be something like `config.extraAllowedContent = 'img[alt,!src]{border-style,border-width,float,height,margin,margin-bottom,margin-left,margin-right,margin-top,width}';` See how the [official image plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/image/plugin.js#L22) deals with it.